# How to play audio, even when mute button is on?

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, avfoundation, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

I'm trying to play an audio file when a button is tapped.

If I step through my code it works, but if I just tap on the button no sound is played.

Here is my code:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
AVAudioPlayer * player;
NSString * path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"soundOne" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL * url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
[player play];
```

Is this the appropriate way to play audio? Nothing is being flagged as being deprecated.

I also see this message in the debugger:

```
AudioQueue: request to trim 0 + 2690 = 2690 frames from buffer containing 1152 frames
```

EDIT:

This code works.

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"soundOne"
                                                     ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:filePath];
self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
                    initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:nil];
[self.audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
self.audioPlayer.currentTime = 0;
[self.audioPlayer play];
```

**How can I play audio with the mute button on?**

Here is the code I have tried for this:

```
CFStringRef state;
UInt32 propertySize = sizeof(CFStringRef);
OSStatus audioStatus = AudioSessionGetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRoute, &propertySize, &state);
if (audioStatus == kAudioSessionNoError) {
    //NSLog(@"audio route: %@", state);
    return (CFStringGetLength(state) <+ 0);
}
return NO;
```

Comment: Just as a side note, you can get URLs out of your bundle with `[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"soundOne" withExtension:@"mp3"]`

Comment: Maybe point those error parameters to some NSError to see what is the actual error? You know... instead of guessing.

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740528/play-sound-on-iphone-even-in-silent-mode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stick this before you call play:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&error];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&error];
```

That should do it.

Comment: @Jayesh It does, that's exactly what this AVSession category is for. In most cases, setting the session to active is not needed though.