# Play sound when device is in silent mode in ios 8 and later

Tags: xcode, ios8, avaudioplayer, audiotoolbox, avkit

As per my title, i am searching any code for playing sound when my device is in silent mode. I am searching from 3days but in ios 8 and later no code is working for silent mode.

Any help would be appreciated. Please pass me any suggestion and advice as soon as possible.

Thanks

Comment: What do you use for play sound?

Comment: NSURL *tapSound   = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource: @"Tock" withExtension: @"aiff"];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef )CFBridgingRetain(tapSound), &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);

Comment: You use system sound. So in silent mode it won't play. I think you can use AVplay and setting like this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740528/play-sound-on-iphone-even-in-silent-mode

Comment: @vienvu Please can u pass me any demo which is working in ios 8 as i am trying this one also it wouldn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use AVPlayer for play file sound and set:

```
let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    try! session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
    try! session.setActive(true)
```

You can check my example code here:[Sample](https://github.com/vienvu89/SampleAvplayer)

Comment: Hi,Is it possible to play sound when app is not running in background and device is in silent mode ?

Comment: @Parth With my currently knowledge, I think it is impossible.