# ios setting to neatly bypass iphone mute

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I am working on an app that, among other things, provides alarms in emergencies. I would like to add a setting that will allow users to receive alarms with sound even if their phone is muted. As far as I am aware, this could be hacked by playing an mp3 through media services, as if the app was a music player left to play in the background, but that doesn't seem extremely kosher.

Does anyone know a 'neater' way to do this? Can I somehow allow my users to prioritise my app over the mute button?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Play sound on iPhone even in silent mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740528/play-sound-on-iphone-even-in-silent-mode)

Comment: @gvuksic Specifically not so. In that one, the clear answer is to use AVAudioSession, which a lot of people are answering, too. I'm asking if there is a neater way, one that won't hijack the music you're playing. One Apple and users would be more agreeable to :)