# AVPlayer does not sound if disabled audio / vibration: on

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avfoundation, avplayer

Hy, I'm trying to understand if there is a way to get sound from the player even when your iPhone is set to silent .. Is there a Swift code to enable the Tone?

```
//IMPOSRT FOUNDATION PER PLAYER
import AVFoundation

        let url = NSURL(string: "https://mywebsite.site/file/\(audio_r!)")
        playerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: url!)
        player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem!)
        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player!)
        playerLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,300,50)
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
        //imposto il volume
        player!.muted = false
        player!.volume = 1.0
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740528/play-sound-on-iphone-even-in-silent-mode

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A playback category should not obey the mute switch

```
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me, my video is fine and the player is not muted and the volume is at max too.