# How to play a sound when iPhone is on silent?

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, avaudioplayer, react-native-ios

I am trying to build a react-native alarm application for iOS. I've had a look at a couple of libraries and the one that seemed like the best suit for my project is react-native-alarm, however I am experiencing a problem with it. When my device is on silent mode, the scheduled local notification that is used to wake up the device and play a sound does not do it. I saw people saying that they've tackled this issue by using AVAudioPlayer API that apple provides but I can't seem to make it work. A bit of guidance and help could be beneficial.

I've followed the explanation here : [Play sound on iPhone even in silent mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740528/play-sound-on-iphone-even-in-silent-mode) and tried to change the code of the library in order to tackle the silent mode without luck.

Here's my code

```
-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^ (UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler {

    completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert | UNNotificationPresentationOptionSound);

    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: nil];
    NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"/Library/Ringtones/Constellation" ofType:@"m4r"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath];
    audioPlay = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];

    [audioPlay play];
}
```

If there's something Im doing wrong or there is an alternative library that could be used in react-native I'd love to hear that. Im not very experienced when it comes to objective-c so that's why I could have done something stupid in this piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set the session to active:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
```

Comment: Hi I added that into userNotificationCenter and there's no sound again. Any other suggestions?